# Save notifications into database in laravel 5.3

Tags: notifications, laravel-5.3, laravel-notification

in laravel 5.3 I use notifications to send mail and save notification to user whenever a successful registration.
I create `Register` extends `Notification` have ToEmail, ToArray

```
public function toMail($notifiable){
   return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com'.print_r($notifiable, true))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
public function toArray($notifiable){
        return [
            'data' => 'A new post was published on Laravel News.'
        ];
    }
```

And in model Use I write function

```
public function routeNotificationForMail(){
        return $this->email;
    }
public function routeNotificationForDatabase(){
        Log::info('run route database');
        return $this;
 }
```

Instruction table `User`(`id`, `email`, `password`)
table `Notifications` (`id`, `type`, `notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`, `data`, `read_at`)
But when register I only email while notification not insert to table.

Update

Thank you @`ABDEL-RHMAN`, but I set `via` method to `return ['database','mail']`
because I can send email notification but not insert to table.
I have a solution ? Thank all

Comment: did you set the `via` method to `return ['database','mail']`